# How do I circumvent a file loader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

In my `webpack.config.js` I have this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!react-svg-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Which I am using to import some svg files directly in Components.

However now I want to show a svg file that resides inside my React App folder via scss only. But the `babel-loader!react-svg-loader` is preventing it from happening. I am loading the scss via React.

This:

```
background-image: url('../assets/icons/pattern/size_35.svg');
```

Becomes

```
background-image: url([object Object]);
```

I can do this but it feels hackish:

```
background-image: url('[FULL_PATH_FROM_ROOT]/assets/icons/pattern/size_35.svg');
```

From my understanding is that for this case I should not have any file loader but because I already have one it's preventing this from working.

I do want to resolve the relative url from the React App though. So that this:

```
background-image: url('../assets/icons/pattern/size_35.svg');
```

becomes this

```
background-image: url('[FULL_PATH_FROM_ROOT]/assets/icons/pattern/size_35.svg');
```

in frontend.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to circumvent your `react-svg-loader` once, you can write the loaders inline:

```
background-image: url('!!file-loader!../assets/icons/pattern/size_35.svg');
```

If this will be a common occurrence, you can use a [resourceQuery](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resourcequery) for the svgs you want to treat as files:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  oneOf: [
    {
      resourceQuery: /file/, // size_35.svg?file
      use: 'file-loader'
    },
    {
      use: 'babel-loader!react-svg-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I only get this error now: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./!!react-svg-loader!../assets/icons/misc/plus.svg"`

Comment: @OZZIE Don't write `./!!react-svg-loader`. Write `!!react-svg-loader` instead.

Comment: I'm not writing that I'm writing: 'background-image:url('!!react-svg-loader!../assets/icons/misc/plus.svg');' but that's the error I get